# Sorting a table with a non-newline record separator in bash

Tags: bash, sort, table

I have a table that looks like

```
'a;b;f|d;e;c|g;h'
```

which I wish to sort by the third column. The output should be

```
'g;h|d;e;c|a;b;f'
```

If I were to use the standard delimiters `whitespace` and `newline` then this could be accomplished using standard `sort`:

```
printf '%b' 'a b f\nd e c\ng h' | sort -k 3
```

would output

```
g h
d e c
a b f
```

The `sort` command can also take a non standard field separator with the `-t` option:

```
printf '%b' "a;b;f\nd;e;c\ng;h" | sort -k 3 -t ';'
```

would output

```
g;h
d;e;c
a;b;f
```

I have however failed to find a way to sort a table with a non-`newline` record separator.

Can this be accomplished? If so, how?

### Edit

A key condition is to alter neither data nor delimiters in the process, only the order in which they appear.

Other tools than the `sort` command are also ok. Preferably POSIX compliant, but not necessarily.

Comment: You can't use `sort` then. The man page says 'The sort utility sorts text and binary files by lines.  A line is a record separated from the subsequent record by a newline (default) or NUL '\0' character'

Comment: If its a delimiter other than `\n` or `\0`, sort is of no help to you. What ever other tools that you could use Awk/Perl or GNU datamash all rely on knowing what the delimiter is `|` and sorts it (like my answer)

Answer (score 4):

The sort command can only sort input records delimited by newline or NUL character as indicated in the manual

> The sort utility sorts text and binary files by lines. A line is a record separated from the subsequent record by a newline (default) or NUL '\0' character

So your transformation at some point would need to know the knowledge of record delimiter (in your case `|`) to arrive at the desired result. Any other commands (Awk/Perl or datamash) would need to make this assumption

---

Not with a single standalone tool, but with `tr`, `sort` and `paste` you could do. You could see how the transformation taking shape, by adding one command at a time to the pipeline

```bsh
echo 'a;b;f|d;e;c|g;h' | tr '|' '\n' | sort -t';' -k3,3 | paste -sd'|' -
```